# Visual Studio: Disable quote wrapping text selection

Tags: visual-studio, editor, selection

When I select a block of text, I and I type a " or a < sign etc. I would like it to simply replace that selected text with the key I press, rather than the new behavior of wrapping the selected text in some "smart" way. I can't find the option to disable this functionality.

Someone asked a similar question about VSCode, but I want to disable this in MSVC for C++.